# Non-Zero Exit Status Installing Package in R-studio (El Capitan)

Tags: r, package

I am trying to install a package onto R, namely "BiOps", this package is no longer in the CRAN repository so I have downloaded the tar.gz file to my mac and directed R to it, however once I do, I get the following:

```
 install.packages("~/Documents/R/R Packages/biOps_0.2.2 (3).tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")    
* installing *source* package ‘biOps’ ...   
** package ‘biOps’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
checking for gcc... clang        
checking whether the C compiler works... yes   
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out  
checking for suffix of executables...   
checking whether we are cross compiling... no  
checking for suffix of object files... o   
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes   
checking whether clang accepts -g... yes     
checking for clang option to accept ISO C89... none needed    
checking how to run the C preprocessor... clang -E      
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep     
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E     
checking for ANSI C header files... yes      
checking for sys/types.h... yes     
checking for sys/stat.h... yes     
checking for stdlib.h... yes      
checking for string.h... yes      
checking for memory.h... yes       
checking for strings.h... yes     
checking for inttypes.h... yes      
checking for stdint.h... yes      
checking for unistd.h... yes      
checking fftw3.h usability... no      
checking fftw3.h presence... no      
checking for fftw3.h... no      
configure: WARNING: Can't find fftw3 header     
checking jpeglib.h usability... no      
checking jpeglib.h presence... no      
checking for jpeglib.h... no       
configure: WARNING: Can't find libjpeg header      
checking tiff.h usability... no       
checking tiff.h presence... no       
checking for tiff.h... no      
configure: WARNING: Can't find libtiff header       
checking for jpeg_destroy_compress in -ljpeg... no      
checking for TIFFOpen in -ltiff... no        
Try static libs needed on OS X      
checking for TIFFOpen in -ltiff... no      
Error: Could not find libtiff.         
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘biOps’      
     * removing     ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/biOps’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘/Users/justinginger/Documents/R/R    
 Packages/biOps_0.2.2 (3).tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

I am at a loose end here. I am studying mathematics with statistics and for my dissertation I want to use this package for image compression. I have been working on this for weeks and am reasonably unfamiliar with code so other similar questions both on here and other websites aren't helping me.I have put in a lot of effort into trying to solve this and really can't get anywhere!

Thank you and Merry Christmas!

Comment: It means the package needs the libtiff and libjpeg dev and library packages installed (and possibly fftw3 as well, for fast fourier transforms?). The README discusses this. Installing these will require some Googling and some basic comfort level with installing things on unix-y platforms from the command line.

Comment: Thanks, will try this now and get back to you.

Comment: Note that the package apparently has not being maintained since almost three years. Don't expect it to play well with up-to-date versions of R.

Comment: Thanks to both of you, I was able to install the missing packages as mentioned by Joran. Roland, luckily I was able to use the package for what I needed without fault so no worries about the up-to-date R versions.